# Using TODAY() in filter criteria field for roll-up summary

Tags: roll-up-summary, criteria-filter

I've read that TODAY() can't be used in filter criteria for a roll-up summary.  Is there any way around this?  I have a field on a detail that tells whether it is from this year, last year, or longer ago than that.  I've tried to make a checkbox that reads this field and gives a boolean, but apparently, that's still not functional.  Is there any way around this?

Flows are out of the question, as I have several hundred thousand records that I would have to loop through.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way around this as such. You cannot use dynamic or formula-based references in Roll-up Summary Field criteria.

I wrote some time ago an article about [Three Routes to Time-Based Rollup Summary Fields](https://www.ktema.org/2019/03/10/three-routes-to-time-based-rollup-summary-fields/). In summary, you can:

- Use a pure-declarative approach using time-based actions (scales poorly).
- Use [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) in scheduled or scheduled + realtime mode.
- Use a full- or partial-Apex solution that includes a scheduled job.

One way or another, you'll have to do an implementation. DLRS in Scheduled mode could be a neat, easy solution to this need.