Roll-up Summary field filter criteria YEAR()
I have a roll-up summary field on a custom object and I want to use a filter criteria to show only records that have been created for the current year. This is not on a report, but when I am actually creating the field on the custom object.
I can do this using the greater than operator 01/01/2024 and less than 31/12/2024, but I want it to be for the year so it doesn't need to be updated in 2025.
What is the best way to do this? Is there any easy way to do this? YEAR() and THIS YEAR, do not seem to work as values as it asks me to enter date format.
Thanks in advance

see this answer - https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/329076/2602
